# Space-efficient encryption/decryption?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

What would be the most space efficient way to encrypt some data such that the encrypted data satisfies any one of the following constraints:

1) Fits in 32 bytes or less of hexidecimal (64 characters)

2) Fits in 28 bytes or less utf-8 characters (28 characters)

3) Fits in a 64 bit unsigned integer

The goal is to encrypt some data (like user id + nonce) and store it publicly on a blockchain and then decrypt it later on a server. The storage requirements of the blockchain I'm using (Stellar memos -- https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#memo).

I'm looking for space-efficient encryption algorithms, or some combination of encryption + lossless compression that could make it fit.

There will be two inputs to encrypt: a user id and a nonce -- let's just assume we can fit both inside of 25 characters.

Example:

```
encrypt("7863439|12343567") -> "385acd1ca0ab619b9f832025fa358b69"
decrypt("385acd1ca0ab619b9f832025fa358b69") -> "7863439|12343567"
```

Comment: Your expectation is contardictional. You want 32 hex char which means 16 bytes data = 128 bit. On the other side you want 32 bit. Explain us better what you need.

Comment: Your requirements make no sense.  What is "it"?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark "it" is the encrypted data. It must satisfy at least one of those requirements.

Comment: @mentallurg Updated to clarify a bit.

Comment: You need to provide similar guarantees for the input data then.  You can't say "must fit in 128 bits" and then expect to provide 2MB of data.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Clarified even more, and added more background to it (although I don't think its really relevant and may make this a more specific question than is needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AES-256 or Twofish-256 You will have 256 bit = 32 bytes. This fits your 1st requirement. Both are space efficient. Well it depends of course how you define "efficient".

Comment: 128 bits is 16 bytes **or** 32 hex encoded characters, not 32 bytes.

Comment: Sure :) Then use AES-256 or Twofish-256 :)

Comment: The bitsize after the algorithm name denotes the key size, not the output size.  I don't think you understood what I meant.

Comment: Yes, it might sound misleading. Twofish uses 128-bit blocks. 256 bits is 2 blocks x encrypted 128 bits. So it fits to produce 256 bits. Same about AES.

Comment: It isn't misleading, you are simply wrong.  The difference between AES-128 and AES-256 has nothing to do with block size nor output size.  I'm not disagreeing that two blocks of output will produce 256 bits, this is obvious.  I'm concerned that your solution was to go from AES-128 to AES-256 to solve issues regarding the size of the output.

Comment: You are right, both would fit, AES-128, AES-256, and even AES-192. And Thowfish.

Comment: Actually Threefish-256 fits, too. And here key size IS connected with the block size. So out of Threefish-256, Threefish-512 and Threefish-1024 only Threefish-256 suits.

Comment: @mentallurg Thanks! AES-256 looks good. Am I correct in saying that if  my input size stays below 32 bytes then the output will also be below 32 bytes?

Comment: @Paul: The answer depends on the mode. AES-256 defines only how a single block will be transformed. But the whole encryption algorithm has one more aspect, the mode of operation. If you use AES-256 in CBC mode, the encrypted result will be longer than the original data. If you use AES-256 in CTR mode and have less that 32 bit input, the output will contain exactly the same number of bits as the input.

Comment: @mentallurg I finally went to implement this and found that there was an interesting twist! I need to have _exactly_ 32 bytes of data, not just below. Would CBC be more appropriate for that now?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could use hashing instead of encryption. Hash your data and store it on a server. Finding input data that will collide with your stored hash is designed to be difficult. Use a strong hashing algorithm that outputs 32 bytes of data, and you're done.

Comment: One of the requirements is to decrypt later.